# Google OAuth2 Service Account Auth with Domain-wide Delegation Using Default Credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

Have anyone been able to get [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) working by using default credentials (i.e. an AppEngine default service account or otherwise derived from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) specifically with the Drive or Gmail API?  We've been able to follow [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/gce-to-adminsdk) to use default credentials with admin sdk APIs, but not with user centric APIs like Gmail/Drive.  We really dislike the key management situation we're stuck in by deploying keys with code or loading them into GCS buckets while knowing that many GCP centric services don't have this problem (i.e. google-cloud-firestore or google-cloud-bigquery python clients).

Comment: Why do you think domain-wide delegation is safer than service account keys? Hint: they are not as these types of credentials have more power than correctly scoped IAM roles applied to IAM member accounts. Suggestion: change your question to ask for the best solution for a specific use case that is clearly defined.

Comment: I don't think domain-wide delegation is safer than service account keys and am not sure where you got that idea.  Domain-wide delegation is necessary for some use cases, and it depends on service accounts to work.  Furthermore, if you want to use domain-wide delegation with drive or gmail, you need to create and manage a key because the don't work with credentials derived from default creds.  Would be nice if default credentials of a service account with domain-wide delegation could be used instead, eliminating a key.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. It would be considered insecure to have access to any services domain-wide with the default keys, so, instead of granting such a big privilege, you are required to generate a new key and give the needed scopes to it.

Comment: Who, exactly, considers default keys insecure, and why?  Default keys are good enough to access literally anything in GCP, which potentially can house just as sensitive data as G Suite can.  Furthermore, default keys are automatically rotated whereas generated keys are not.  There are many more attack vectors on a generated key than a default one, I cannot find any reason why a generated key would be less secure than default.

Comment: This does not talk about default keys security, it talks about a design principle on hierarchical systems that offer resilience over fault tolerance and malicious software design:

As such, it's a very ancient principle, highly hierarchical organizations need to protect its kernel from internal and external attacks, to do it so, external layers should only have the minimal information needed to perform its own organizational tasks, this is a common principle for non-democratic human social organizational forms such as armies, religious sects and capitalist enterprises.

Comment: This principle was then ported to computation using the same argument: we have a highly hierarchical system and we need to protect its core, to make it so, it announces something like this: "Do not give more rights to any program or application than the ones needed to perform its intended task "

Comment: It's called the Principle of least privilege:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: Generating a key to a service account doesn't widen or narrow the scope of access the service account has access to, in only enables you to run as that service account in other computing environments.  That creates a new attack vector, where the key is copied to other locations.  I don't think anything you've mentioned has any merit in this context.  By running the code within GCP, we are not copying keys anywhere, maintaining the same level of rights with or without the key, and relying on Google to rotate them (instead of having to write code to do that ourselves).

Comment: Generating a key to a service account doesn't widen or narrow the scope of access the service account has access to: 
It does, but it does it for G Suite Applications, what you call User Centric ones, on where there is sensible data and is not a good practice to give by default all of the possible scopes, instead, an approach from nothing to all is required.

Comment: I think what you're talking about is enabling domain-wide delegation, which certainly does widen the scope.  I'm not here to debate if someone should use DWD or not though, what I'm after is a good key management solution.  Since the code runs in GCP there is an opportunity for the key to be managed by Google, which I consider a far stronger security posture than creating one and loading it somewhere never to be rotated.